# How to route all requests to index.php, route non-existing files to error page, use pretty URLs, and add trailing slashes?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

How can I do all these together in my .htaccess file?

- route all incoming requests to index.php
- route non-existing files to an error page
- rewrite the URLS to the pretty versions (without the .php)
- automatically add trailing slashes for SEO purposes

I already know how to do these separately but am having a tough time getting them to work together. Here's what I've got so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /apps/louis/

#if file doesn't exist, try grabbing the .php version of it and continue on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,N]

#if .php file doesn't exist, route to the index page with a 404 code and "error" param so index page knows to display error content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pageName=error [QSA,NC,R=404,L]

#if request name is not empty, route to the index page with a param of the page name so it knows which content to display
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pageName=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

#as long as the requested URL isn't an image or CSS file or script, tack on a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
```

What am I doing wrong? I added comments to describe what I think should happen, so please correct me if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /apps/louis/

#as long as the requested URL isn't an image or CSS file or script, tack on a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

#if file doesn't exist, try grabbing the .php version of it and continue on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#if .php file doesn't exist, route to the index page with a 404 code and "error" param so index page knows to display error content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?pageName=error [QSA,L]

# existing files are routed to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)(.+)$ index.php?pageName=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Very close! But can you please also include the other bit where for valid pages it should redirect to index.php?pageName=$1 (from my post above).

Comment: Non existing files can either go to error page or `index.php?pageName=$1`. Otherwise you need to have a finite set of valid pages that you need to list in .htaccess

Comment: Right, but where would I squeeze in the logic that tells it to forward existing files to index.php?pageName=$1 (where $1 is the REQUEST_FILENAME). Your solution sends it off directly to the .php page instead of the index.php page, which is the singleton handler of all requests--valid and error.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot again, but still doesn't work. Now it redirects almost everything to the default ISP error page (without even going through index.php?pageName=error. Only the homepage works and when I explicitly include the .php, such as /contact-us.php

Comment: Made another minor edit. This is working fine for me on my Apache. It redirects existing files to `index.php?pageName=...` and all non-existing files to `index.php?pageName=error`